# No valid training data were found

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-classification

I'd like to use randomforest to create a classification model, but when I want to classify landcover in 1986, it always says the error:

> No valid training data were found.

Here's my code:

```
var dp2021 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1")
                  .filterDate('1986-01-01', '1986-12-31')
                  .map(maskL8sr)
                  .median();
//                  
var mndwi = dp2021.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B6']).rename('MNDWI');
var ndbi = dp2021.normalizedDifference(['B6', 'B5']).rename('NDBI');
var ndvi = dp2021.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
var nir = dp2021.select("B5");
var red = dp2021.select("B4");
var rvi = nir.divide(red).rename('RVI');
var dvi = nir.subtract(red).rename('DVI');
dp2021 = dp2021.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndbi).addBands(mndwi).addBands(rvi).addBands(dvi);
//
var classNames = egblf.merge(crop).merge(land).merge(water).merge(other);
var bands = ['B1','B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7','MNDWI','NDBI','NDVI','RVI','DVI'];
//
var training = dp2021.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: classNames,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 30
});
// 
var withRandom = training.randomColumn('random');
//
var split = 0.7; 
var trainingPartition = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
var testingPartition = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));
//
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(1001).setOutputMode('REGRESSION').train({
  features: trainingPartition,
  classProperty: 'landcover',
  inputProperties: bands
});
//
var class_img = dp2021.select(bands).classify(classifier);
//
var test = testingPartition.classify(classifier);
//
var confusionMatrix = test.errorMatrix('landcover', 'classification');
print('confusionMatrix',confusionMatrix);
print('overall accuracy', confusionMatrix.accuracy());
print('kappa accuracy', confusionMatrix.kappa());

Map.centerObject(dp_roi);
Map.addLayer(dp_roi);
Map.addLayer(class_img.clip(dp_roi), {min: 1, max: 6, palette: ['green', 'yellow', 'orange','blue','black']});
Map.addLayer(dp2021.clip(dp_roi),{bands:["B3","B4","B5"],gamma:1.5,max:1000,min:0});
Export.image.toDrive({ 
        image: dp2021.clip(dp_roi).int16(), 
        description:"dp_1986",
        folder: "dp", 
        region: dp_roi, 
        scale: 30, 
        crs: "EPSG:4326", 
        maxPixels: 34e10 
      });
```

Comment: We can't run your code to reproduce your results, because `maskl8sr`, `egblf`, `crop`, `land`, `water`, and `other` are missing. Please provide a **complete, runnable** sample — that's really the only way to troubleshoot these kinds of problems.